# How to set order by in Sql for temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In #temp table I am getting my values as

```
Month         Sales
JUN 2015    600.00
JAN 2015    5000.00 
MAR 2015    3500.00 
MAY 2015    1000.00 
FEB 2015    1500.00 
APR 2015    1400.00
```

How to update #temp table for order by month and alter table by modified changes, I used `order by DATEPART(mm,CAST( Substring( Month, 1, CharIndex( ' ', Month ) - 1)+ ' 1900' AS DATETIME)) asc` but changes were not reflected when fired select on #temp

Expected Output:

```
Month        Sales
JAN 2015    5000.00
FEB 2015    1500.00
MAR 2015    3500.00
APR 2015    1400.00
MAY 2015    1000.00
JUN 2015    600.00
```

So next time if I do `select * from #temp`, I should get the expected output

Comment: Without using `ORDER BY` there is not any guarantee for showing a sorted result ;).

Comment: How inserted value in temp table?

Comment: using `select * into #temp from( select * from market where userid=@userid) `   I also tried using order by here but i didn't got the expected output

Comment: @Steph what is the exact output you are expecting?

Comment: example of data to Market specify

Comment: @Shashank : I specified it in the Expected Output above- Actually after getting this thing perfectly I need to perform some math operations so this select is not my last select statement

Comment: Solved :) -     `Create Table #tempo(srno numeric identity(1,1),Month varchar(20),Sales numeric(18,2)) ` and then inserting  data by orderbydate `insert into #tempo(Month,[Sales(INR)]) SELECT  * From (select * from market where userid=@userid) k  order by  Convert(datetime,Month)`

Comment: Tables have **no** inherent order. If you don't have an `order by` clause on the query that *reads* the data from the temp table, there is *no* guarantee on the order in which rows will appear. Your "solved" comment is incorrect. You happen to have constructed a query that, in your limited testing, *appears* to offer the behaviour you're looking for. But the correct answer is that there's no way to *guarantee* the behaviour you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Just do **`CAST(MonthVal AS DATE)`**

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(MonthVal VARCHAR(10), Sales DECIMAL(8,2)) 

INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES
('JUN 2015', 600.00 ),
('JAN 2015', 5000.00), 
('MAR 2015', 3500.00), 
('MAY 2015', 1000.00), 
('FEB 2015', 1500.00), 
('APR 2015', 1400.00)

SELECT
    *
FROM
    @Table 
ORDER BY
    CAST(MonthVal AS DATE)
```

Comment: nice and short. Just keep in mind: does not work before SQL Server 2k8

Answer (score 2):

Make your temp table have an additional integer, auto-incremented (`identity`) Primary Key column. Now, when you insert into that table in a certain order, this order will be kept.

**Edit**

As the order can only be computed after the contents of the temp table has been assembled, the introduction of an additional integer column (`id`) - *not* an identity column - might help. This should be set to the month's numerical equivalent by a suitable `update` statement and can then be used to sort the temp table's contents. See here for a little example: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/336013/default-order-of-temp-table?opt.textResults=true

But in any case, the `order by id` clause must always be used.

Comment: I need to add identity but after the rows are sorted month wise

Comment: Well, yes, that is the price you have to pay. Resetting the "implicit order" of a table is, as far as I know not possible as such. But you *can* insert the contents of a first temporary table into a second one (having the `identity` column) in the "right order" which will then be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (Month varchar(10),sales decimal(18,2))

insert into @t (Month,sales)values ('JUN 2015',600.00),
('JAN 2015', 5000.00 ),
('MAR 2015',3500.00 ),
('MAY 2015',1000.00 )

select MONTH,sales from @t order by DATEPART(MM,month)
```

Comment: Its the same thing i was doing, you are selecting but as I said its not my final select so I need this table to be as expected for further process, I also tried to get this output in another temp table but it didn't worked