# Execute sql script statement output order is not follow the script statement order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following script to execute the sql script statement then insert the output into the temp table. For some reason, the output result is not insert according to the ORDER BY ADDEDDTTM DESC. Does anyone know how can I solve this issue?

```
declare @stm nvarchar(Max), @ID int = NULL;
set @stm = 'SELECT TOP 5000 * FROM test WHERE ADDEDDTTM >= ''2019-02-01'' AND ADDEDDTTM < ''2019-03-01'' ORDER BY ADDEDDTTM DESC ';

CREATE TABLE #temp ( [ID] [int], [AddedDttm] [datetime], [MessageID] [varchar](100), [MessageParentID] [varchar](255), [UR] [varchar](20), 
    [SeqNumber] [bigint], [MsgControlID] [varchar](255), [MsgStd] [varchar](12), [MsgType] [varchar](12), [SendApp] [varchar](100), 
    [SendFacility] [varchar](100), [SendAgency] [varchar](100), [RcvApp] [varchar](100), [RcvFacility] [varchar](100),
    [Campus] [varchar](100), [ServiceName] [varchar](40), [ExecutionTime] [int], [ErrorMsg] [varchar](1000), [MsgDateTime] [datetime],
    [HopCount] [int], [MsgVer] [char](10), [ServiceVer] [char](10), [Payload] [varbinary](6000), [PatientType] [varchar](50),
    [Ward] [varchar](40), [Bed] [varchar](40))


INSERT INTO #temp execute (@stm )
    SELECT  ID as 'mhie_message_id', 
            AddedDttm as 'logged_datetime', 
            UR as 'ur', 
            MsgType as 'type', 
            Campus as 'campus', 
            ServiceName as 'service_name', 
            ErrorMsg as 'error_message'
    FROM #temp
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set order by in Sql for temp table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31376739/how-to-set-order-by-in-sql-for-temp-table)

Comment: Rows in a relational database have no "order". The only way to get a guaranteed order is to use `order by` in your SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no warranty on any select of any kind of any specific order if not stated directly by a ORDER BY.

Comment: Even a clustered Index won't guarantee the order of the data. It *might* cause data to be returned in the same order with **small** datasets but it's more "luck" than anything. Once you start introducing all the rest of the parts of the data engine, like partitions, parallelism, etc then things just start to become "random" again. The only true way is as you first stated; use an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: It's not really. The remark you made on the clsutered index doesn't really help matters. You state it makes it a "better chance", but that's not actually true. I'm not sure the post is worth the downvote (it's not mine), as your first point is true, but what you've said here isn't strictly correct in regards to the index

Comment: @Larnu i'll just edit that part out if it might cause confusing, when i say "chance" it means all down to factors you have no control over. Thanks